# OpenXava - create list with all modules

Tags: java, crud, openxava

Is there any way I can create simple start page for OpenXava. I mean page with links to all modules for example:

1. People
2. Invoices
3. Etc...

Would be great to have solution out of the box.
I haven't found anything in documentation with this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is maybe not the answer you wanted but I would really like you to think twice before choosing that framework.

You might prefer another one with a strong community behind it (note that your answer is the only one tagged `openxava` in the whole site), like for example: [Grails](http://www.grails.org/)

And lastly don't get confused by that marketing line that says that OpenXava is faster than Rails and others. It is simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the framework and it enables one to create CRUD application very fast. Its is also very customizable on on the business logic and on the User interface. The only thing that stopped me from using it is the fact that i have to deploy it inside a portal server such as liferay. Am still figuring out how to create my own lightweight navigation and security framework for it.